# adb shell: Exception occurred while executing 'size':

Tags: android, adb

I ran the following command:

```
adb shell wm size 480x480
```

and got the following result:

```
Exception occurred while executing 'size':
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: not implemented: display=480x480 cutout=DisplayCutout{insets=Rect(0, 45 - 0, 0) waterfall=Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=0} boundingRect={Bounds=[Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(152, 0 - 328, 45), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)]}}
    at com.android.server.wm.utils.WmDisplayCutout.computeSafeInsets(WmDisplayCutout.java:120)
    at com.android.server.wm.utils.WmDisplayCutout.computeSafeInsets(WmDisplayCutout.java:55)
    at com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.calculateDisplayCutoutForRotationUncached(DisplayContent.java:2249)
    at com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.lambda$fiC19lMy-d_-rvza7hhOSw6bOM8(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$DisplayContent$fiC19lMy-d_-rvza7hhOSw6bOM8.compute(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.android.server.wm.utils.RotationCache.getOrCompute(RotationCache.java:57)
    at com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.calculateDisplayCutoutForRotation(DisplayContent.java:2233)
    at com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.configureDisplayPolicy(DisplayContent.java:2105)
    at com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.reconfigureDisplayLocked(DisplayContent.java:1512)
    at com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.setForcedSize(DisplayContent.java:3146)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setForcedDisplaySize(WindowManagerService.java:5900)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerShellCommand.runDisplaySize(WindowManagerShellCommand.java:230)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerShellCommand.onCommand(WindowManagerShellCommand.java:77)
    at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.onShellCommand(WindowManagerService.java:1280)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:965)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:839)
    at android.view.IWindowManager$Stub.onTransact(IWindowManager.java:3711)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.onTransact(WindowManagerService.java:1542)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1195)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
```

All the other sizes worked ok. This command also performed a reset on the device the first time. But thereafter the error continues to be displayed but no reset.

Comment: What device (model name and manufacturer) and which Android version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

In android developer options try turning on the "Disable permission monitoring" setting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).